# Python: 16 bit HDR RGB image

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I am working on HDR images (Python3). I have a **companded HDR image** (uint16, shape = (1855,2880)) which is of the format RGGB.

I want to process this image, but firs convert it to RGB and display it.

I am able to do this easily on MATLAB using:

```
img_rgb_16 = demosaic(hdr_img,'rggb');
img_rgb_8 = tonemap(double(img_rgb_16));
```

I can view the RGB output, it is 1860x2880x3 uint8.

However, I want to perform this in Python. I did:

```
img_rgb_16 = cv2.cvtColor(hdr_img, cv2.COLOR_BAYER_RG2RGB)
```

The output `img_rgb_16` appears blank white (`plt.imshow(img_rgb_16) ;  plt.show()`) (with light shades of grey).

`img_rgb_16.max() = 60214`
`img_rgb_16.min() = 182`
`convertedImage.shape = (1855, 2880, 3)`
`dtype=uint16`

I know I have to tonemap it, I did not understand what function to use.

Can someone help me?

Edit:

Experts, please correct me if I'm wrong:
This is not a simple divide by "n" kind of problem, since the image is HDR and there are several pixels which become too dark / too bright. I need a function to "tonemap", not simply convert from 16 bits to 8 bits.

Comment: divide by 2**16. matplotlib expects floats in the range of 0 .. 1

Comment: With the RGGB layout, it sounds like you're dealing with a raw file.  Debayering is only one small part of getting a usable image from that.  The last step of the process will probably be converting from linear levels to sRGB.

Comment: Also take some research on the debayering in opencv. Afaik the codes' names (like cv2.COLOR_BAYER_RG2RGB) can be misleading.

Comment: the *very* recent releases have patches that introduce "sane" naming for bayer patterns.

Comment: @MarkRansom, thanks. Yes, I'm dealing with raw images. It is companded, should I use the decompanded images (linear) instead?
What would the additional steps be, apart from Debayering?

Comment: I definitely think you need to start with decompanded images, I don't see how debayering would work otherwise.  Unfortunately I don't know much about converting raws, but one thing I know is that the edges of a camera sensor are masked off so you can calculate which level corresponds with true black.

Comment: @MarkRansom: My decompanded images are 32bit float. Do you know how I can convert them to RGB for further processing?

Comment: @Saania you've got 32 bit float values but you haven't done debayering yet?  That's a very unusual setup.